# Possible number of combinations from a subset

Tags: discrete-mathematics, combinations

Let's say I have an set of elements like this: [0,1,2,3,4,5]. I want to figure out the max number of possible combinations using a max of 4 elements. Meaning using 2 or 3 is also a possibility:

[0]
[0,1]
[2,5,4]
[5,1,0,4] >> Using the max amount of elements.

Ay suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: How about the trivial case of no elements?  May we use the "empty" subset?

Comment: @hardmath Nope, need at least one element present.

Comment: is [0,1] the same as [1,0]?

Comment: @Alessandro Yes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the [binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) $\binom nk$ which gives the number of combinations of $k$ elements of $n$ objects. Thus you are looking for $$\sum_{k=1}^4 \binom 6k$$ Since $\sum_{k=0}^6 \binom 6k = 2^6$ we have

$$\sum_{k=1}^4 \binom 6k=2^6-\binom 60-\binom 65-\binom 66=2^6-1-6-1=2^6-8$$ different combinations.

Comment: You want the summation from $k=1$ to $4$, not $k=1$ to $5$.

Comment: @DivergentQueries: You are right. I corrected it... ;-)

Comment: it should be $\binom 60$ and $\binom 65$ instead of $\binom 06$ and $\binom 56$

Comment: This is it!!!! Thanks so much!